# annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

When I run this code it was shows this kind of error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roomController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.Room.Dao.RoomDao com.Room.Controller.RoomController.roomDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.Room.Dao.RoomDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

How can I solve this error?

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/service/user/")
public class RoomController {

@Autowired
RoomDao roomDao;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")
public String getAllUsers() {
    String users="hello welcome";
    return users;
}

public List<RoomMembers> getRoomMembers() {
    List<RoomMembers> roomMemberList=roomDao.listMember();
    //User user=userService.getUserById(id);
    return roomMemberList;
}
}
```

Model class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="RoomMembers")
public class RoomMembers{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "memberId")
private int memberId;

@Column(name="memberName")
private String memberName;

@Column(name="Phone")
private long phone;

@Column(name="address")
private String address;

public int getMemberId() {
    return memberId;
}

public void setMemberId(int memberId) {
    this.memberId = memberId;
}

public String getMemberName() {
    return memberName;
}

public void setMemberName(String memberName) {
    this.memberName = memberName;
}

public long getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(long phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}


}
```

Dao:

```
public interface RoomDao {

public List<RoomMembers> listMember();

}
```

DaoImpl:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class RoomDaoImpl implements RoomDao{

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<RoomMembers> listMember() {
    List<RoomMembers> roomMemberList= (List<RoomMembers>)  sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(RoomMembers.class).list();
    return roomMemberList;
}

}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:resources/database.properties" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.Room.Controller" />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/>


<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
    <list>
        <value>com.Room.Model.RoomMembers</value>
    </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>             
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Comment: check your <context:component-scan base-package="com.Room.Controller" />, possible your dao impl out of the scanning

Comment: You're doing the component-scan in `com.Room.Controller`, do you have your components there?

Comment: Where you have defined **RoomDao** bean? I don't see it in the xml file.

Comment: [{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)} also a solution to autowired error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60220058/unable-to-create-junit-test-for-spring-boot-controller/65456509#65456509)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Document :](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html) context component scan is used scan for classes(annotated) to create beans.

In your case `roomDao` is a bean which has to create while initializing. But in your case you are just scanning controllers,so only controller bean will be created **not** others which present other than `com.Room.Controller` package.

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.Room.Controller" />
```

So **make it to scan all annotated classes**. Then all required(annotated) beans will be created and `BeanCreationException` will go.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times when you develop a springboot application and perform dependency injection in other classes, you get an error stating

```
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

This is because the Main of the application resides in a package for example
`(com.example.project)`

and your other packages have a different naming structure such as

```
com.example.entites,
com.example.services,
com.example.repositories
```

And hence, your `(main class)` cannot find these other packages automatically.

What you have to do to resolve this problem, is to name your other packages to follow the **(main) package structure**, so it scans them automatically, so you have the error bean problem resolved.

So now our package structure will have to be (refactored) and (renamed) as follows:

```
com.example.project.entities
com.example.project.services
com.example.project.repositories
```

And voila!!!, the main class scans all the other packages automatically, since it is within its folder.

Don't forget, **(a package) is a folder**, hence, all the other **(packages) are stored within the (package)** and hence, it can easily find the **other folders within** it.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same error and my solution i needed   put:

```
@Service
```

in my service. i hope help you. XD